# SSIS Column Names automatically changed to F2,F3.....F13

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a XL source file, the first column contains the name, 199001,19902.....,199012,

In SSIS package using XL source if click the 1st column contains headings it automatically covert my heading as name,F2,F3.....F13.

But i need as it is like Name,199001,19902,.....,199012 as a heading than i am using unpivot transformation and convert the column into row to my staging table.

Please sort out my problem i need the XL column like i mentioned above( Name,199001,19902,.....,199012 )

Thanks in advance

Thanks,

Pinku

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because SSIS detects the column names as numeric. In the Excel sheet, force them to be characters by adding a single quote to the start of the field data.
(i.e. `'199001`).
The column names should then be imported correctly.

I've tested this on SSIS 2005.